# mysql stored procedure in c# winform

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, stored-procedures

I created a transaction in my winform with mysql database with some insert statements.How to use those insert statements as stored procedure.

Comment: you want to send some insert statement in sp and want to execute them in SP. The reason why you want to do in this manner will impact the type of answer you get here.

Answer (score 0):

The following might be of use...

### MySQL

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users
(
user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
username varchar(32) unique not null
)
engine=innodb;

insert into users (username) values ('foo'),('test');

select * from users order by user_id;


drop procedure if exists update_user;

delimiter #
create procedure update_user
(
in p_user_id int unsigned,
in p_username varchar(32)
)
proc_main:begin
    update users set username = p_username where user_id = p_user_id; 
end proc_main #

delimiter ;

call update_user(2,'bar');

select * from users order by user_id;
```

### C# non sproc (console example)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace TransDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string DB_CONN_STR = "Persist Security Info=False;Username=foo_dbo;Password=pass;database=foo_db;server=localhost;Connect Timeout=30";
            const int DB_TIMEOUT = 30;

            MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(DB_CONN_STR);
            MySqlCommand cmd = null;
            MySqlTransaction trx = null;

            Console.WriteLine("Updating...");

            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                string sqlCmd = "update users set username = @username where user_id = @user_id";

                cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCmd, cn);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = DB_TIMEOUT;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "beta");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", 2);

                cmd.Prepare();

                trx = cn.BeginTransaction();
                cmd.Transaction = trx;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                trx.Commit();

                Console.WriteLine("Update complete");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(trx != null) trx.Rollback();
                Console.WriteLine("oops - {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Dispose();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

### C# sproc (console example)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace TransDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string DB_CONN_STR = "Persist Security Info=False;Username=foo_dbo;Password=pass;database=foo_db;server=localhost;Connect Timeout=30";
            const int DB_TIMEOUT = 30;

            MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(DB_CONN_STR);
            MySqlCommand cmd = null;
            MySqlTransaction trx = null;

            Console.WriteLine("Updating...");

            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                string sqlCmd = "update_user";

                cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCmd, cn);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = DB_TIMEOUT;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_username", "alpha");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_user_id", 2);

                // cmd.Prepare(); // no need to prepare it's a stored proc

                trx = cn.BeginTransaction();
                cmd.Transaction = trx;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                trx.Commit();

                Console.WriteLine("Update complete");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(trx != null) trx.Rollback();
                Console.WriteLine("oops - {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Dispose();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

hope this helps :)

---